# Tactics for Array/List simplification in lean4

Tags: lean4, tactic

Because there are both Arrays and Lists in Lean4, sometimes you end up with code that has a mixture of Lists and Arrays interspersed with basic operations and conversions between the two.  For example, I needed to prove something like this as part of a larger theorem:

```
lemma foo (a b: Array _): { data := Array.data a ++ (Array.data b ++ [Array.data c]) : Array (List _)} = a ++ (b ++ [Array.data c])
```

How should I approach proving these sorts of lemmas? Are there tactics or library lemmas I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the tools for working with programming-like objects (`Array`s and such) can be found in either core Lean (`Init` which is imported automatically) or in the standard (programming) library `Std`.  You can find a lot of useful lemmas in `Std`.  For `Array`s they are stored in [`Std.Data.Array.Lemmas`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Std/Data/Array/Lemmas.html).

Further, to prove that two structures are equal, it is enough to use the `congr` tactic.  (Note from a theorem-proving perspective `Array`s are just defined as structures wrapping a list `data`.  Of course that is not actually the internal implementation.) So in the end you get a short proof of your lemma:

```
import Std.Data.Array.Init.Lemmas

theorem foo (a b: Array (List α)) (c : Array α) :
    { data := a.data ++ (b.data ++ [c.data]) : Array (List _)}
    = a ++ (b ++ [c.data]) := by
  congr -- useful for proving two structures are equal
        -- new goal: a.data ++ (b.data ++ [c.data]) = (a ++ (b ++ [c.data])).data
  simp  -- uses simp lemmas from Std.Data.Array.Init.Lemmas
```

Note, `simp` looks up "simp lemmas" from other parts of the code, so you have to import `Std.Data.Array.Lemmas` to access the simp lemmas for `Array`.

Lean 4 is still under development, and even moreso `Std`.  So if you find lemmas for `Array` or `List` or other standard objects that would be useful to have, either ask about it on the Lean Zulip, approach one of the maintainers of https://github.com/leanprover/std4, make an issue on that repo, or make a PR to that repo with your new lemmas.

---

Update: As you noted in the comment, this two line proof may not always work, and I should be more clear that it likely won't work for many applications.  Here are a few observations:

- Theorem proving is in general challenging.  While Lean and other proof assistants strive to make powerful automation that make the job of the user easier, this itself is no easy task.
- If you plan to prove a lot about `Array`, you may find it useful to look through the proofs in [`Std.Data.Array.Lemmas`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Std/Data/Array/Lemmas.html) in more detail to see how they are done.
- As for searching for theorems and lemmas, the three best approaches I know in Lean 4 are `library_search` (example below), the search feature in [the docs](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs), and asking around (on here or the Lean Zulip).
- I notice that the `Array` lemmas are often stated as `<expression for an array>.data = ...` and I think if you state your lemmas in that format then you would find that `simp` tactic works much of the time for simple equations.  As for getting your lemma in that format, let me mention how I was able to solve your new example (found in the comments).

I want a way to turn `x = {data := y}` into `x.data = y`.  I don't know the name of the theorem or even where to look, but I suspect there is a theorem similar to the following and I use the `library_search` tactic to find it.

```
import Std.Data.Array.Init.Lemmas
import Mathlib.Tactic.LibrarySearch

example (r: Array α): r.data = x -> r = { data := x } := by
  library_search  -- exact fun a ↦ Array.ext' a
```

While that exact fact wasn't in the library, `library_search` gives me a proof of my fact, and I see that [`Array.ext'`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Data/Array/Basic.html#Array.ext%27) is what I basically need.  So then I apply `Array.ext'` and it is now in the form I can use `simp`:

```
import Std.Data.Array.Init.Lemmas

theorem bar (r: Array α) (b: List α): r ++ b = { data := r.data ++ b } := by
  apply Array.ext'
  simp
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my example, but it seems to struggle with a simpler lemma of this sort: `lemma bar (r: Array α) (b: List α): r ++ b = { data := r.data ++ b }`  Even when importing `Std.Data.List.Init.Lemmas` as well.  Is this the result of a missing lemma, or are there more tricks needed for these sorts of proofs?

Comment: I was able to solve it using `rw [← Array.appendList_data]`, but is there an easier way that doesn't require me manually searching for lemmas?

Comment: @JeremySalwen See my edits.

Comment: @JeremySalwen Also the `congr` proof seems to work with the symmetric goal, `{ data := r.data ++ b } = r ++ b`.  That is a bit annoying, but good to know.